# How to get Lauch time of an ios application

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to ios mobile testing. I need to get the launch time of an ios application. How would i do that using java or is there any other way to do it. Any advise on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you developing using Java?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is achievable in java since the iOS development is in Obj-C/Swift. However I'll answer your question.

You can get the launchDate `DateTime.Now` that start at the AppDelegate `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOption` and get the finishLoadDate `DateTime.Now`on the ViewDidload method of the first View Controller that shows. And then compare these both dates to track the time difference.

This way you can track the time from the app was clicked, till the app was launched.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Of you could get NSDate at launch and then NSDate on viewDidLoad and calculate the timeInterval between them.

Comment: Thanks @TawaNicolas your approach is better than mine, I updated my answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things happens before the system executes willFinishLaunchingWithOption.
So all you need to do in order to understand it, it's to set the environment variable DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS.

Just click on edit scheme then select Run and set DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS as and environment variable under arguments tab.

After that you will be able to see launching time in your debug console.

Answer (score -2):

Haven't tested this, but it should help you get your solution:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSDate *fetchStart = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *fetchEnd = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeElapsed = [fetchEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:fetchStart];
    NSLog(@"Duration: %f seconds", timeElapsed);

    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will not get the time from the app launched till it loaded, the 2 times are directly get on the did launch when the app did not get fully loaded yet.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it will help arrive at a solution. Please encourage others to find their own solutions by guiding them, not providing the solution itself.